# how to edit search area in drupal

Tags: css, drupal, templates, search

In my site www.rchealth.co.uk, I want to add the search.

I have enabled the search module and the search block is in the header, now I want to customize the search look and feel to look better.

I have searched and found some methods like http://systemseed.com/blog/how-customise-search-box-drupal-6 and http://drupal.org/node/154137

I followed the steps but I am still unable to edit the template. My drupal version is 6.17

i pasted this code in template.php

```
function accordlaw_preprocess_search_block_form(&$vars, $hook) {
  // Modify elements of the search form
  unset($vars['form']['search_block_form']['#title']);

  // Set a default value for the search box
  $vars['form']['search_block_form']['#value'] = t('Search RC Health');

  // Add a custom class to the search box
  // Set yourtheme.css > #search-block-form .form-text { color: #888888; }
  $vars['form']['search_block_form']['#attributes'] = array(
     'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = '".$vars['form']['search_block_form']['#value']."';} this.style.color = '#000000';",
     'onfocus' => "if (this.value == '".$vars['form']['search_block_form']['#value']."') {this.value = '';} this.style.color = '#000000';"
  );

  // Modify elements of the submit button
  unset($vars['form']['submit']);

  // Change text on the submit button
  //$vars['form']['submit']['#value'] = t('Go!');

  // Change submit button into image button - NOTE: '#src' leading '/' automatically added
  $vars['form']['submit']['image_button'] = array('#type' => 'image_button', '#src' => base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/images/search-button.png');

  // Rebuild the rendered version (search form only, rest remains unchanged)
  unset($vars['form']['search_block_form']['#printed']);
  $vars['search']['search_block_form'] = drupal_render($vars['form']['search_block_form']);

  // Rebuild the rendered version (submit button, rest remains unchanged)
  unset($vars['form']['submit']['#printed']);
  $vars['search']['submit'] = drupal_render($vars['form']['submit']);

  // Collect all form elements to print entire form
  $vars['search_form'] = implode($vars['search']);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "unable to edit the template". The modifications are not showing ? What did you really add in the file, post your code.

Comment: what do you want to do with the search box?

Comment: I want to remove the text Search this site: want to make the button an image reduce the width of input field an place a background image around the search area. also i just noticed that when i am loged in with admin its showing the search on all pages, but if i browse the site with some other browser without login it the search doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

You say the search block is in the header... do you mean the **theme** search? The code you are using is for the *block* search form.

The most likely reason that you can't see the search form when not logged in as administrator is that you have not given the correct permissions to use 'search' to anonymous (and possibly authenticated) users.

To change the look/feel/functionality of the *theme* search in the header of your theme, you can always use a template file (`search-theme-form.tpl.php`) as well.

Copy search-theme-form.tpl.php from "/modules/search" and paste it into your theme directory. Make any edits you want, then clear your cache at "www.example.com/admin/settings/performance".

More information on using `search-theme-form.tpl.php`:
[search-theme-form.tpl.php (Drupal Docs)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search-theme-form.tpl.php/6)
[How to Theme the Search Form for Drupal 6](http://www.pixelclever.com/how-to-theme-search-form-drupal-6)